# How can I get the exact program name via PID ？

Tags: linux, shell

I googled a lot, and most of the answer is `ps -p $PID -o comm=`,
but I find this result is not precise -- sometime it is truncated.

```
$ pidof transmission-daemon
1169

$ ps -p 1169 -o comm=
transmission-da
```

So, what is the correct way to get the exact program name (not truncated one) via PID ?

Comment: I found that `cat /proc/3823/status | grep -i name` works well

Answer (score 1):

From [`man ps`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html):

> `-C cmdlist`
>
> Select by command name.  This selects the processes whose
> executable name is given in `cmdlist`.  NOTE: The command   name is not
> the same as the command line. Previous   versions of procps and *the
> kernel truncated this command   name to 15 characters*. This limitation
> is no longer   present in both. If you depended on matching only 15
> characters, you may no longer get a match.

(emphasis mine)

and:

```
$ printf 'transmission-da' | wc
      0       1      15
```